# Casting to a string for numeric sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a set of numbers and I need to generate a string-hash that is sortable for these numbers. The numbers can be integers or floats, for example:

```
-5.75E+100
-4
-1.74E-101
1.74E-101
5
9
11
52.3
5.75E+100
```

I think to do non-exponents for integers and floats it would be simple:

```
                                    # whatever the padding needs to be
>>> sorted(map(lambda x: str(x).zfill(10), [-4, 5, 52.3]))
['-000000004', '0000000005', '00000052.3']
```

However, what would be a more comprehensive way to generate a string-hash here that would sort properly for the above list of numbers? I am fine prepending exponents, if necessary (or converting everything to an exponent, if required), and encoding negative numbers in complement code, if that's required too.

Comment: Considering how python handles integers it seems like your hash could get very large if you don't want collisions. Do you have some limits on input?

Comment: @Mark let's say a valid javascript number type, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number.

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: You say hash, but it seems like you just want to compare them for sorting purposes. And numeric types are already comparable to each other (with the exception of `complex`, but it's always weird). Why not just compare the numeric values?

Comment: @ShadowRanger it's part of a typed function that returns a string (it's not implemented in python, I'm just using this conceptually to show what I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `float` object has a built-in function `hex()` that will convert it to a hex string.  That's almost enough to make a sortable string, but there are a few problems.

First, negative numbers have a leading `-` but positive numbers don't have anything.  You need to add a leading character to positive numbers.

Second, `-` comes *after* `+` in the sorting order.  You need to replace one or the other to make the order correct.

Third, the exponent comes at the end of the string.  It needs to get moved to the front of the string to make it more significant, but the sign needs to stay at the absolute front.

Fourth, the exponent is a variable number of digits.  It needs to be zero filled so that it has a consistent size.

Putting it all together produces something like this:

```
def sortable_string(number):
    hex_num = float(number).hex()
    if not hex_num.startswith('-'):
        hex_num = '+' + hex_num
    hex_num = hex_num.replace('-', '!')
    hex_parts = hex_num.split('p')
    exponent = hex_parts[1][0] + hex_parts[1][1:].ljust(4, '0')
    return hex_parts[0][0] + exponent + hex_parts[0][1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
nums = sorted(map(eval, data))
nums = list(map(str, nums))
nums
```

Output -

```
['-5.75E+100', '-4', '-1.74E-101', '1.74E-101', '5', '52.3', '5.75E+100']
```

Comment: that gives a number though, I need a string that sorts properly.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Check the updated answer. Does that help you?

Comment: Not sure why you're bothering with `num.replace("E", "* 10 **")`; `1e10` and `1E10` are both perfectly legal `float` literals; you don't even need `eval`, `ast.literal_eval` could parse them all safely with no text manipulation at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh so I can straight up apply eval on it to convert it into a number? And what is `ast`here?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya: `ast` is a module that grants direct access to Python's Abstract Syntax Tree (it's a built-in; ships with every Python install), and, as a bonus, provides the `literal_eval` function, which can take any string representing a legal Python literal (`tuple`, `list`, `set`, `dict`, `int`, `float`, `bytes`, `str`, etc.) and convert it to the actual Python value.